# How to validate combinations of values with Parsley?

Tags: parsley.js

I'm trying to write a validator for phonenumbers for [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org). The phone-number form widget consists of two fields:

```
<div>
  <select name="country">
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
  </select>
  <input type="tel" name="number" data-parsley-phonenumber>
</div>
```

The validation function that I use looks like this:

```
function validatePhoneNumber(country, number) {
  // return true if valid else false.
}
```

I'm aware of the [Custom Validator example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/customvalidator.html) in the documentation, but it seems to only work if I hardcode a global selector for the country select field into the validator attribute `data-parsley-phonenumber='["global-selector-here"]'`

Is there a way to solve this without such a global selector? or more specific: is there a way to access the `ParsleyField.$element` inside the validator function? What's the recommended way of doing multi-field validations with parsley?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the way you refered (with `data-parsley-phonenumber="#country"` and then access the value with the `requirement` parameter), like this:

```
<input type="tel" name="number" data-parsley-phonenumber="#country" />
<script>
    $('#myForm').parsley();

        window.ParsleyValidator
            .addValidator('phonenumber', function (value, requirement) {
                var select = $(requirement).parsley().$element;

                // call your function with the text of the selected option
                return validatePhoneNumber(select.find(":selected").text(), value);

            }, 32)
            .addMessage('en', 'phonenumber', 'En message');
</script>
```

If you don't want to do this, you can access the ParlseyField object inside your `addValidator`, like this:

```
<input type="tel" name="number" data-parsley-phonenumber />
<script>
    $('#myForm').parsley();

        window.ParsleyValidator
            .addValidator('phonenumber', function (value, requirement) {

                var select = $("select[name=country]").parsley().$element;

                // call your function with the text of the selected option
                return validatePhoneNumber(select.find(":selected").text(), value);

            }, 32)
            .addMessage('en', 'phonenumber', 'En message');
</script>
```

Note that you need to be sure to define the `addValidator` after you have `$('#myForm').parsley();`.

Comment: Since the jquery selector is not limited to the current form this does only work if my form is the only one with a field named country.

Comment: I see. As a work around, you may try to pass something like `data-parsley-phonenumber="#myform|#country"` and in your custom validator split that string by `|` and access the form id and the field id inside that form. This is not a elegant solution, I can't see another option to solve your issue.